# Azure IoT Hub IoT devices page shows permission error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-iot-hub, azure-sas

On the Azure IoT Hub's "IoT devices" page I am getting an error:

```
Unable to retrieve devices. Please ensure a Shared access policy is enabled with necessary permissions [Registry Write Service Connect]
```

1. I checked the Shared Access Policy `iothubowner` has all permissions (Registry read/write, service connect and device connect)
2. I'm the only user on the subscription
3. I checked the Activity Log and it shows that I've successfully run the Get all IoTHub Keys operation.

Other potential context:

- I've recently been working with ARM templates and SAS policies to enable an Azure function to be triggered from IoT Hub Lifecycle Events --> Event Hub --> The Azure Function. When removing/adding resources is it possible that I removed a required SAS policy somehow?
- I've been creating/working with the IoT Hub's Message routing
- I've been provisioning/deleting non-IoT Hub resources with ARM templates and the resource groups they create recently.

Any idea why Azure says the permissions are missing? What would the next debugging step be?

Comment: Related thread Microsoft Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/306681/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this was a transient issue on Azure's side:
learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/306681/index.html